# How can we instantiate a BLE connected peripheral in every view controller swift class instead of a Singleton?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi I have a Swift app that I'm trying to learn.
Iam using Adafruit Basic Chat as a reference.

https://github.com/adafruit/Basic-Chat/tree/master/Basic%20Chat

How can I pass the connected peripheral to another view controller scene, without a singleton class?

I have gone through a lot of links but can someone tell me the simplest form of code to extend the peripheral scope to all my view controller activities?

I am able to read and write data using the following code but how can I clear the RX buffer after I have received the data as I sometimes find the rx data seems to overwrite the received bytes.

```
// BLECentralViewController


//
//  BLECentralViewController.swift
//  Basic Chat
//
//  Created by Trevor Beaton on 11/29/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Vanguard Logic LLC. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth


var txCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic?
var rxCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic?
var blePeripheral : CBPeripheral?
var characteristicASCIIValue = NSString()



class BLECentralViewController : UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    //Data
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    var RSSIs = [NSNumber]()
    var data = NSMutableData()
    var writeData: String = ""
    var peripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []
    var characteristicValue = [CBUUID: NSData]()
    var timer = Timer()
    var characteristics = [String : CBCharacteristic]()

    //UI
    @IBOutlet weak var baseTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBAction func refreshAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        disconnectFromDevice()
        self.peripherals = []
        self.RSSIs = []
        self.baseTableView.reloadData()
        startScan()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.baseTableView.delegate = self
        self.baseTableView.dataSource = self
        self.baseTableView.reloadData()

        /*Our key player in this app will be our CBCentralManager. CBCentralManager objects are used to manage discovered or connected remote peripheral devices (represented by CBPeripheral objects), including scanning for, discovering, and connecting to advertising peripherals.
         */
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Disconnect", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        disconnectFromDevice()
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        refreshScanView()
        print("View Cleared")
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        print("Stop Scanning")
        centralManager?.stopScan()
    }

    /*Okay, now that we have our CBCentalManager up and running, it's time to start searching for devices. You can do this by calling the "scanForPeripherals" method.*/

    func startScan() {
        peripherals = []
        print("Now Scanning...")
        self.timer.invalidate()
        centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [BLEService_UUID] , options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:false])
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 17, target: self, selector: #selector(self.cancelScan), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    /*We also need to stop scanning at some point so we'll also create a function that calls "stopScan"*/
    func cancelScan() {
        self.centralManager?.stopScan()
        print("Scan Stopped")
        print("Number of Peripherals Found: \(peripherals.count)")
    }

    func refreshScanView() {
        baseTableView.reloadData()
    }

    //-Terminate all Peripheral Connection
    /*
     Call this when things either go wrong, or you're done with the connection.
     This cancels any subscriptions if there are any, or straight disconnects if not.
     (didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic will cancel the connection if a subscription is involved)
     */
    func disconnectFromDevice () {
        if blePeripheral != nil {
            // We have a connection to the device but we are not subscribed to the Transfer Characteristic for some reason.
            // Therefore, we will just disconnect from the peripheral
            centralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(blePeripheral!)
        }
    }


    func restoreCentralManager() {
        //Restores Central Manager delegate if something went wrong
        centralManager?.delegate = self
    }

    /*
     Called when the central manager discovers a peripheral while scanning. Also, once peripheral is connected, cancel scanning.
     */
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        blePeripheral = peripheral
        self.peripherals.append(peripheral)
        self.RSSIs.append(RSSI)
        peripheral.delegate = self
        self.baseTableView.reloadData()
        if blePeripheral == nil {
            print("Found new pheripheral devices with services")
            print("Peripheral name: \(String(describing: peripheral.name))")
            print("**********************************")
            print ("Advertisement Data : \(advertisementData)")
        }
    }

    //Peripheral Connections: Connecting, Connected, Disconnected

    //-Connection
    func connectToDevice () {
        centralManager?.connect(blePeripheral!, options: nil)
    }

    /*
     Invoked when a connection is successfully created with a peripheral.
     This method is invoked when a call to connect(_:options:) is successful. You typically implement this method to set the peripheral’s delegate and to discover its services.
     */
    //-Connected
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("*****************************")
        print("Connection complete")
        print("Peripheral info: \(String(describing: blePeripheral))")

        //Stop Scan- We don't need to scan once we've connected to a peripheral. We got what we came for.
        centralManager?.stopScan()
        print("Scan Stopped")

        //Erase data that we might have
        data.length = 0

        //Discovery callback
        peripheral.delegate = self
        //Only look for services that matches transmit uuid
        peripheral.discoverServices([BLEService_UUID])


        //Once connected, move to new view controller to manager incoming and outgoing data
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let uartViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UartModuleViewController") as! UartModuleViewController

        uartViewController.peripheral = peripheral

        navigationController?.pushViewController(uartViewController, animated: true)
    }

    /*
     Invoked when the central manager fails to create a connection with a peripheral.
     */

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to connect to peripheral")
            return
        }
    }

    func disconnectAllConnection() {
        centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(blePeripheral!)
    }

    /*
     Invoked when you discover the peripheral’s available services.
     This method is invoked when your app calls the discoverServices(_:) method. If the services of the peripheral are successfully discovered, you can access them through the peripheral’s services property. If successful, the error parameter is nil. If unsuccessful, the error parameter returns the cause of the failure.
     */
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        print("*******************************************************")

        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let services = peripheral.services else {
            return
        }
        //We need to discover the all characteristic
        for service in services {

            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            // bleService = service
        }
        print("Discovered Services: \(services)")
    }

    /*
     Invoked when you discover the characteristics of a specified service.
     This method is invoked when your app calls the discoverCharacteristics(_:for:) method. If the characteristics of the specified service are successfully discovered, you can access them through the service's characteristics property. If successful, the error parameter is nil. If unsuccessful, the error parameter returns the cause of the failure.
     */

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        print("*******************************************************")

        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {
            return
        }

        print("Found \(characteristics.count) characteristics!")

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            //looks for the right characteristic

            if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(BLE_Characteristic_uuid_Rx)  {
                rxCharacteristic = characteristic

                //Once found, subscribe to the this particular characteristic...
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: rxCharacteristic!)
                // We can return after calling CBPeripheral.setNotifyValue because CBPeripheralDelegate's
                // didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic method will be called automatically
                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                print("Rx Characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")
            }
            if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(BLE_Characteristic_uuid_Tx){
                txCharacteristic = characteristic
                print("Tx Characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")
            }
            peripheral.discoverDescriptors(for: characteristic)
        }
    }

    // Getting Values From Characteristic

    /*After you've found a characteristic of a service that you are interested in, you can read the characteristic's value by calling the peripheral "readValueForCharacteristic" method within the "didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service" delegate.
     */
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

        if characteristic == rxCharacteristic {
            if let ASCIIstring = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                characteristicASCIIValue = ASCIIstring
                print("Value Recieved: \((characteristicASCIIValue as String))")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: nil)

            }
        }
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverDescriptorsFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("*******************************************************")

        if error != nil {
            print("\(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }
        if ((characteristic.descriptors) != nil) {

            for x in characteristic.descriptors!{
                let descript = x as CBDescriptor!
                print("function name: DidDiscoverDescriptorForChar \(String(describing: descript?.description))")
                print("Rx Value \(String(describing: rxCharacteristic?.value))")
                print("Tx Value \(String(describing: txCharacteristic?.value))")
            }
        }
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("*******************************************************")

        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error changing notification state:\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")

        } else {
            print("Characteristic's value subscribed")
        }

        if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
            print ("Subscribed. Notification has begun for: \(characteristic.uuid)")
        }
    }



    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("Disconnected")
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error discovering services: error")
            return
        }
        print("Message sent")
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error discovering services: error")
            return
        }
        print("Succeeded!")
    }

    //Table View Functions
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.peripherals.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //Connect to device where the peripheral is connected
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BlueCell") as! PeripheralTableViewCell
        let peripheral = self.peripherals[indexPath.row]
        let RSSI = self.RSSIs[indexPath.row]


        if peripheral.name == nil {
            cell.peripheralLabel.text = "nil"
        } else {
            cell.peripheralLabel.text = peripheral.name
        }
        cell.rssiLabel.text = "RSSI: \(RSSI)"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        blePeripheral = peripherals[indexPath.row]
        connectToDevice()
    }

    /*
     Invoked when the central manager’s state is updated.
     This is where we kick off the scan if Bluetooth is turned on.
     */
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn {
            // We will just handle it the easy way here: if Bluetooth is on, proceed...start scan!
            print("Bluetooth Enabled")
            startScan()

        } else {
            //If Bluetooth is off, display a UI alert message saying "Bluetooth is not enable" and "Make sure that your bluetooth is turned on"
            print("Bluetooth Disabled- Make sure your Bluetooth is turned on")

            let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Bluetooth is not enabled", message: "Make sure that your bluetooth is turned on", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
            alertVC.addAction(action)
            self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}





//UART SCENE


//
//  UartModuleViewController.swift
//  Basic Chat
//
//  Created by Trevor Beaton on 12/4/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Vanguard Logic LLC. All rights reserved.
//





import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class UartModuleViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    //UI
    @IBOutlet weak var baseTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var switchUI: UISwitch!
    //Data
    var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager?
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral!
    private var consoleAsciiText:NSAttributedString? = NSAttributedString(string: "")


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Back", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
        self.baseTextView.delegate = self
        self.inputTextField.delegate = self
        //Base text view setup
        self.baseTextView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        self.baseTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        self.baseTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        self.baseTextView.text = ""
        //Input Text Field setup
        self.inputTextField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        self.inputTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        self.inputTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        //Create and start the peripheral manager
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        //-Notification for updating the text view with incoming text
        updateIncomingData()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.baseTextView.text = ""


    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // peripheralManager?.stopAdvertising()
        // self.peripheralManager = nil
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

    }

    func updateIncomingData () {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: nil , queue: nil){
            notification in
            let appendString = "\n"
            let myFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15.0)
            let myAttributes2 = [NSFontAttributeName: myFont!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red]
            let attribString = NSAttributedString(string: "[Incoming]: " + (characteristicASCIIValue as String) + appendString, attributes: myAttributes2)
            let newAsciiText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.consoleAsciiText!)
            self.baseTextView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: characteristicASCIIValue as String , attributes: myAttributes2)

            newAsciiText.append(attribString)

            self.consoleAsciiText = newAsciiText
            self.baseTextView.attributedText = self.consoleAsciiText

        }
    }

    @IBAction func clickSendAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        outgoingData()

    }



    func outgoingData () {
        let appendString = "\n"

        let inputText = inputTextField.text

        let myFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15.0)
        let myAttributes1 = [NSFontAttributeName: myFont!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue]

        writeValue(data: inputText!)

        let attribString = NSAttributedString(string: "[Outgoing]: " + inputText! + appendString, attributes: myAttributes1)
        let newAsciiText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.consoleAsciiText!)
        newAsciiText.append(attribString)

        consoleAsciiText = newAsciiText
        baseTextView.attributedText = consoleAsciiText
        //erase what's in the text field
        inputTextField.text = ""

    }

    // Write functions
    func writeValue(data: String){
        let valueString = (data as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        //change the "data" to valueString
        if let blePeripheral = blePeripheral{
            if let txCharacteristic = txCharacteristic {
                blePeripheral.writeValue(valueString!, for: txCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
            }
        }
    }

    func writeCharacteristic(val: Int8){
        var val = val
        let ns = NSData(bytes: &val, length: MemoryLayout<Int8>.size)
        blePeripheral!.writeValue(ns as Data, for: txCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
    }



    //MARK: UITextViewDelegate methods
    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        if textView === baseTextView {
            //tapping on consoleview dismisses keyboard
            inputTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:250), animated: true)
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:0), animated: true)
    }

    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
            return
        }
        print("Peripheral manager is running")
    }

    //Check when someone subscribe to our characteristic, start sending the data
    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didSubscribeTo characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
        print("Device subscribe to characteristic")
    }

    //This on/off switch sends a value of 1 and 0 to the Arduino
    //This can be used as a switch or any thing you'd like
    @IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if switchUI.isOn {
            print("On ")
            writeCharacteristic(val: 1)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Off")
            writeCharacteristic(val: 0)
            print(writeCharacteristic)
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        outgoingData()
        return(true)
    }

    func peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error)")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The peripheral keeps disconnecting and starts scanning soon as I start a new view controller using performsegue method.

It would be really helpful if someone could shed some light?

Comment: Even if you don't use a singleton you still need a single object to manage your CoreBluetooth stack; handing scanning, connection, read/write etc.  Pass the once instance of this object between your view controllers

Comment: Hi paulw11, would you please be able to tell me how to pass the peripheral object? And is singleton more recommended over passing an object?

Comment: Singletons are frowned upon because they can make unit testing more difficult. You would pass your Bluetooth manager object to each new view controller in prepareForSegue if you are using segues or just set it on the new VC if you aren't using segues.

Comment: Thanks Paulw11, so I have got a piece of code as soon as I receive an RX packet then I perform a segue using performsegue with identifier and call the segue name string so how can I put the peripheral into an object and pass it with that method? Could you give me an example ? Thanks

Comment: Hi paulw11, Thanks for your response I have worked out how its done by your comment. really appreciate your response.